# jar file executes in linux but not in windows

Tags: java, database

My code executes perfect in linux, but i copy the "dist" folder to windows and i execute the jar file and i get this:
**C:\Users\luilli\Desktop\baseDeDatos>java -jar baseDeDatos.jar
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link fai
lure**.
My code is the following:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package basededatos;


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
/**
 *
 * @author luilli
 */
public class BaseDeDatos {

     public static String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tienda";
     public static String user="root";
     public static String password="foobarbaz";
    
     public static Connection getConnection()
     {
         Connection con=null;
         try{
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
           con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"conexion exitosa");
         }
         catch(Exception e){
             System.out.println(e);
         }
         return con;
     }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    Connection con=null;
    con=getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet res;
    ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from todos");
    res=ps.executeQuery();
    while(res.next())
    {
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,res.getString("nombre"));
        System.out.println(res.getString("nombre"));
    }

    con.close();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Is there a database up and running on windows?

Comment: oops! it was that. Tank you.